# Как поменять цвет компонента в зависимости от его числа? JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

у меня есть текст в котором отображается количество процентов:

```
<p className='percent_style' >{`${res.percent}%`}</p>
```

css:

```
.percent_style {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #4BB34B;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 1px 2px 1px 2px;
}
```

В передаваемой `res.percent` разные значения, мне нужно чтобы цвет был в зависимости от числа.

Comment: И в чем именно возникли сложности?

Comment: @SwaD, не знаю как и где это писать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/806083/javascript-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 0):

Это можно реализовать следующим образом:

Создаем функцию, которая на основе процентов будет нам возвращать код цвета. Я сделал вот такую простую функцию:

```
  const getRGBC = (perc) => {
    const color = Math.round(255 - 255 * perc / 100);
    return `${color}, ${color}, ${color}`;
  }
```

Далее в render мы указвыаем нужный цвет

```
<p style={{color: `rgb(${getRGBC(res.percent)})`}}>{res.percent}%</p>
```

---

P.S.: Реализация функции создания кода цвета приведена исключительно для примера, так же как и указание цвета в `rgb()`